# How is pandas rolling std calculated?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a simple dataframe as follows:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([np.nan, np.nan, 0.004, 0.002, -0.002, 0, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 1e-8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])

               0
0            NaN
1            NaN
2   4.000000e-03
3   2.000000e-03
4  -2.000000e-03
5   0.000000e+00
6            NaN
7            NaN
8            NaN
9   1.000000e-08
10  0.000000e+00
11  0.000000e+00
12  0.000000e+00
13  0.000000e+00
14  0.000000e+00
15  0.000000e+00
16  0.000000e+00
17  0.000000e+00
18  0.000000e+00
19  0.000000e+00
```

When I apply a `rolling` with a window size of 6 and a `min_periods` of 3, and then a `.std()`, I'd expect that the last value in the resulting dataframe would be calculated from the last 6 values in `df`, i.e. from `[0,0,0,0,0,0]` which should yield 0. Instead, however, `df.rolling(6, min_periods=3).std()` yielded the following output:

```
               0
0            NaN
1            NaN
2            NaN
3            NaN
4   3.055050e-03
5   2.581989e-03
6   2.581989e-03
7   2.581989e-03
8   2.000000e-03
9   1.154703e-03
10  5.773517e-09
11  5.773517e-09
12  5.000011e-09
13  4.472145e-09
14  4.082491e-09
15  8.148571e-12
16  8.148571e-12
17  8.148571e-12
18  8.148571e-12
19  8.148571e-12
```

where the last value, 8.148571e-12 is clearly not the standard deviation of the last 6 values in `df`.

Comment: For most practical purposes... it is zero

Comment: You could also just round to the 10th decimal place `df.round(10)`